# Django - querying with ForeignKeys

Tags: django, orm

These are my models:

```
class Delivery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_(u"Name"), max_length=50)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Content(models.Model):
    delivery = models.ForeignKey(Delivery)
    title = models.CharField(_(u"Title"), max_length=300)
```

Having the content_id, I'm trying to make a query to return a content by id, but verifying if the user has the permission. When querying the Delivery object I do this:

```
 delivery = get_object_or_404(Delivery, pk=self.kwargs['pk'], permissions=self.request.user)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to do the same, but querying the Content object. I'm trying to query like this

```
obj = Content.objects.get(Q(pk=self.kwargs['pk']), Q(delivery.permissions=self.request.user))
```

but the result is "keyword can't be and expression"

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use django [relation lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
Content.objects.get(delivery__permissions=self.request.user)
```

I'm not really getting what you are trying to do with `Q` though?

Comment: Thanks, just what a needed. The query now is like this: obj = Content.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'], delivery__permissions=self.request.user).